# How to format custom column in jsonGrid (Extjs)

Tags: jquery, asp.net, extjs

I already have amount column and want to put currency from DB in that column itself. How can I do with same format?

```
{ 
   headerText: 'Total', 
   dataField: 'AmtTotal', 
   sortable: true, 
   dataType: 'number', 
   formatString: '{0:N2}', 
   align: 'right' 
}
```

I want to put currency beside it.. How can I do it with celltemplate? I also want to preserve formatString {0:N2}

Comment: Have a look here http://www.objis.com/formationextjs/lib/extjs-4.0.0/docs/api/Ext.grid.column.Number.html

Comment: You mean to say that you are already having a amount column 'Total' with some data in which you want to display currency(from DB) as well?

Comment: Thanks for information. I used renderer/buildTemplate for the same.